# Reading a csv from url

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to get the first chunk listed below to replicate the second chunk. However, I've noticed in jupyter that when I try to get to the same table; it displays it differently (the first chunk looks like a nice dataframe and the second just looks like a plain table). Is there a difference between the two methods? The other thing I have also noticed is that the first method the column 'cases' comes out in dtypes while in the second chunk it displays something different. Thanks!

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-counties.csv'
states = pd.read_csv(url, 
                     usecols=['date', 'county', 'state', 'cases'],
                     parse_dates=['date'],
                     squeeze=True
                    ).sort_index()
states = states.loc[states['state'] == 'Alabama']
states = states.drop(columns=['state'])
states.set_index(['county', 'date'], inplace=True)
states.dtypes
```

cases    int64

dtype: object

```
url = 'https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/states/daily.csv'
states = pd.read_csv(url,
                     usecols=['date', 'state', 'positive'],
                     parse_dates=['date'],
                     index_col=['state', 'date'],
                     squeeze=True).sort_index()

states.dtypes
```

dtype('float64')

Answer (score 1):

In the second dataframe, there are `NaN` values, which forces a conversion to `float`. For more details on this, see the documentation on the new [nullable integer datatype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).

Comment: I get your point here, which really helps. I just don't understand why the two dataframes look different in my jupyter notebook. What I'm trying to do is replicate an example with the same type of data from a different source (example uses state and I'm trying to use county data) and it is not working so I thought it had something to do with the way I was reading the csvs.